# Getting rid of wchar_t size linker warning

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, wchar-t, linker-warning

I compile my Android NDK library with `-fshort-wchar`. I know the RTL assumes 4-byte  wchar_t, I know what I'm doing, the library **works**. However, on every build linker gives me the following warning for every object file:

> ld.exe: warning: MyFile.o uses 2-byte wchar_t yet the output is to use 4-byte wchar_t; use of wchar_t values across objects may fail

When I provide

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := --no-wchar-size-warning
```

This gives me an "unrecognized option" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `APP_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning` (to `Application.mk`) works fine for me on NDKs at least as early as r7.

I assume it would work just the same as:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning
```

Comment: The option is supported in ARM and Intel linkers, but not on MIPS, for some reason. However, the MIPS linker doesn't compain about wchar_t size in the first place. A little ifneq() does the trick...

Comment: It complains thanks to an ARM-specific tag in the object files, and I guess such a feature is missing from the MIPS standard.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [this](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2008-07/msg00125.html)? The post explains that the `--no-wchar-size-warning` option will make the linker treat the mismatch as a warning, not an error. As in the enum case, the authors choose to display the message anyway.

You don't see the effect of setting this flag in your project because as detailed [elsewhere](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-07/msg01440.html), using `-fshort-wchar` automatically adds `-Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning`.