# android cmake error uses 2-byte wchar_t yet the output is to use 4-byte

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake

I'm trying to compile my ndk library by using cmake, but I can only build x86 and x86-64. When I tried armeabi-v7a , the Build Output said:

```
  C:/Users/use/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/17.2.4988734/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: warning: CMakeFiles/engine.dir/cfiles/bt.c.o uses 2-byte wchar_t yet the output is to use 4-byte wchar_t; use of wchar_t values across objects may fail
  
  
  C:/Users/use/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/17.2.4988734/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld: error: treating warnings as errors
  
  clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have read some issues like:
[Getting rid of wchar_t size linker warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060106/getting-rid-of-wchar-t-size-linker-warning)

I tried `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -W1 --no-wchar-size-warning` in ndk-build ways to compile and it works.

But I don't know how to make it works in cmakelist.txt
I tried:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS " -W1 --no-wchar-size-warning")
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS " -W1 --no-wchar-size-warning")
```

However, it doesn't work.

Is that the compile and link flags must write in the build.gradle?

I tried to write `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "XXXXX")` in `cmakelist.txt` but it doesn't work too.
I write `cppFlags = "XXXXX"` in the build.gradle and it works.

Thanks for ur attention!

Comment: what it seems to be saying is that a library was compiled with a 2 byte w_char and not 4 byte. what is the the full warning line. are u shure ur not trying to link x86 binarys to arm

Comment: @JesseTaube  Thank you for your comment! I'm not trying to link binarys to arm but to compile library with c files. I have solved this problem by writting this in cmakelist.txt. `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -W1 --no-wchar-size-warning")`